# WPF MVVM - TwoWay Binding of dynamically generated TextBoxes does not update

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In a wpf app of mine, I'm trying to dynamically generate TextBoxes in a WrapPanel by a `ObservableCollection<string>` named `VariableList`. I'm using the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` for this.
The XAML code looks like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:myViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
.........
 <ItemsControl
     Grid.Column="0"
     Grid.Row="1"
     ItemsSource="{Binding VariableList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
     VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Height="20"
                 Width="100"
                 Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

The generation of the TextBoxes works, so the view can access the viewmodel. Also, other TwoWay bindings with static elements works. But somehow this ObservableCollection will never be changed my the View. Have I missed something I'm not aware of? Does TwoWay Binding even work with dynamical TextBoxes?
I've allready tried to link a Command to the TextChanged-Event to read the values but this also wont get me the new textbox values.

Comment: A Binding can not replace an element in a collection, see the duplicate question. In general, a non-empty property path is required for a TwoWay Binding. As a note, `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding are pointless. Also, for the Text Binding, `Mode=TwoWay` is the default value.